# Parse Push Alway error APNS - Invalid token

Tags: parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

Parse Push Alway error APNS - Invalid token!

but I got 1 device installed in Core > _Installation Class
and it's got deviceToken (but when send push,it's always say invalid token)

I use parse send Push but no device recieve and got error

APNS - Invalid token
Invalid token, the user might have uninstalled the app. x1

I've already upload .p12 to setting
and use 'noneProduction'

but I test in http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/

and upload .pem which create from same .p12
and use same deviceToken and use 'Sandbox mode'

It's work but Parse.com not work....